# I am trying to communicate between a r307 finger print sensor and a Django website using arduino and esp32

Tags: django, iot, arduino-uno, fingerprint, arduino-esp32

I am creating a Django website which reads finger prints and replies in true or false using the r307 finger print sensor, arduino and Esp32. Can anyone guide me how to do that.

I have connected the finger print sensor with the arduino IDE and it enrolls and verifies finger prints successfully but I can not figure out how to connect it with my website. I am making a Django project. All I want it it read the fingerprint and respond in true or false.

Comment: Take a look at various WiFi examples come with your ESP32 installation on how to use a WiFiClient to send data to a server. Write your Django code accordingly to handle the route for incoming message.